# Google Docs file adds two new lines instead of one

Tags: google-docs

> NOTE
>   This was cross-posted on the Google Docs official help forum:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/H24s-PNTn1E

I've been using Google Docs for a quite long time and today I noticed that the behaviour of those documents has changed.

When you have text like:

```
M

M
```

And copy & paste that text into a text editor like Notepad. The text is separated by two lines:

```
M


M
```

This has affected old files as well as new ones.

This has been tested on Windows 10 with Chrome and on Mac Os (El Captain) with Chrome. Tried both on normal and incognito tabs.

Comment: Hi Ivanka, I can confirm your findings.

Comment: OK. What's your question?

Comment: Why is that happening and how to avoid it?

Comment: This doesn't happen to me. I'm tried on a Chromebook. What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: @Rubén Windows 10 (as well on Mac El Captain) with Chrome.

Comment: Please try again in incognito mode. If the problem persist, please tell us if you have Google Docs add-ons installed.

Comment: @Rubén same thing happens in incognito tabs. I have no Google Docs extensions installed.

Comment: I just tried on Windows 10 with Chrome. It is inserting single line breaks. I'm wondering if an update to Google Documents is being rolled out.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra: Have you seen similar reports on GPF?

Comment: @ruben, No, wanted to ask.....but haven't yet done that.

Comment: @IvankaTodorova: I suggest you to send feedback to Google from the app (Help > Report a problem) and to post a question on the Google Docs official help forum https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/docs

Comment: @Rubén thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: @Rubén as you may have seen I posted in GPF and it's a known issue they are looking into it. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: I subscribed to your GPF post I got the related notification. I hope that this will be fixed soon. I'm still wondering about why this happens just to "few" users and not to all.

Comment: @Rubén and for some users it happens only to **some** of their files...

Comment: Another weird thing, why the move conversation chat feature from this site was not triggered yet?

Comment: @Rubén and here it is. Answering your question =D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47940/discussion-between-ruben-and-ivanka-todorova).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. See [Extra space when pasting from Google Docs to Notepad++ Webforms](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/aETEdA9QXDs) (the cross-post was marked as a duplicate of this thread)